# How to find the rotation matrix from SVD?

Tags: matrix, computer-vision, linear-algebra, svd

I have used the SVD to find the rotation matrix between two sets of points. I know that `R = Transpose(U) * V` but I do not understand what U and V stand for and why this multiplication results in the rotation matrix.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs in SignalProcessing or MathOverflow

Answer (score 6):

As your question is theoretical and makes no reference to any programmes or a specific problem, you would be best off writing your question in [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/).

Nevertheless, to give you a general idea, (which you should definitely reinforce with solid facts): 
The linear algebra behind the singular value decomposition (svd) essentially describes (in the simplest case) what happens to a vector, when it is multiplied by a matrix.

At a small scale, if you multiply a vector(v) by a matrix (R), you obtain a second vector (u). Unless the matrix 'R' is unitary, the new vector you get will have a different direction and magnitude to the first.
In other words, the product of matrix 'R' on the vector 'v' will produce a **Rotation** and a **Stretching** (or Compressing) of vector 'v', which will transform into vector 'u'.

If you make vector 'u' be unitary, and multiply it by a new variable (σ) that holds its original magnitude, you are basically doing: **R·v=u·σ**

At a larger scale, when v and u are no longer vectors but big matrices, the formula is: **R·V=U·∑**

The reason why it was useful to make 'u' become unitary is that unitary matrices have a cool property: There transposed is equal to their inverse!

So, you can re-arrange the formula to look like: R=U·∑·V(transposed)

Hence, you can obtain the 'Rotation matrix' with this formula, where U and V(t) are orthonormal matrices that hold vector directions, and ∑ holds the magnitudes (or singular values) of said vector directions.

For a more detailed explanation, I suggest this lecture to you: [Lecture: The Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EokL7E6o1AE)